# Variance of independent variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_k$ and $Y_k$ be two stochastic variables whose joint distribution is the regular normal distribution on $(\mathbb{R}_2,\mathbb{B}_2)$ with mean 0 and variance matrix

$\begin{align*}
\Sigma_k=\begin{pmatrix}  
\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 &   \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}$

for $k ∈ \mathbb{N}$. That is, $(X_k,Y_k)^T ∼ N(0,Σ_k)$.

My problem is now that if we let $Z = X_2Y_2$ i have to show that 
 $VZ=\frac{1}{4}$. I know that $X_2$ and $Y_2$ are independent, but how do I find the variance of the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $X_2^2$ is independent of $Y_2^2$, hence $\mathbb E\left[Z^2\right]=\mathbb E\left[X_2^2\right]\cdot\mathbb E\left[Y_2^2\right] =1/2\cdot 1/2$.
Since $X_2$ and $Y_2$ are independent and centered, so is the product $X_2Y_2$, hence $\mathrm{Var}(Z)=\mathbb E\left[Z^2\right]$.

Comment: Thank you, it was a great help!